# Laravel - How to run a function/controller every minute ? (Task Scheduling)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron

I have a controller method that I want to run every minute. I read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling) for Task Scheduling but it seems to document Commands only.

Is there any way that I can use it to call a route/controller method/script every minute ?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Acc;

class ScriptController extends Controller
{
    public function updateAcc()
    {
        $c = new Scripts\AccountA();
        $xoo = $c->getInfo();
        $z = json_decode($xoo,true);

        $data= new Acc();
        $data->price = $z["result"];
        $data->save();
    }
}
```

I need to use the *DB facades* and *external classes* etc...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, just like the documentation states, you can make a call to any function. So you can do the following:

```
$schedule->call(function () {
    $controller = new \App\Http\Controllers\ScriptController();
    $controller->UpdateAcc();
})->everyMinute();
```

However, it is **very bad practice** to call a controller out of its web context, you should create a facade or a job that executes the code you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can write a a shell script that will make a CurlRequest to your controller, and add the shell script to a cron job. or you can use laravel commands and call the controller by a request.

why not using the code inside the controller in a command?