# Use Laravel schedule to run a controller function in everyMinute

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I have tried to use Laravel Scheduler to run a controller function everyMinute but not working

This is my `app\console\kernel.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // $schedule->command('inspire')
        //          ->hourly();
        $obj = new HomeController();

        $schedule->call(function () use ($obj) {


            $obj->daily_set_profit(); //call method


        })->everyMinute();
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: are you getting any error ?

Comment: @MuhammadFaranAli neither any error nor get getting my desired result

Comment: i try to run `daily_set_profit()` function to get daily commission on my site but not get any commission yet

Comment: did you run this in your terminal ?
php artisan schedule:run

Comment: i have not used it before  thats why i have not enough experience in scheduler of laravel ... can you help me to use it ???how i run my controller function daily or everyMinute

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46075200/laravel-how-to-run-a-function-controller-every-minute-task-scheduling] i write code after seen this post

Comment: you have to run this: ```php artisan schedule:run```

Comment: Open your terminal, then type `php artisan schedule:run`

Comment: first, you should study on task scheduling and cronjob. then try again

Comment: ok sir  where i can study cronjob have you any useful link related this? @AlImrunShowrov

Comment: yes sir i run this on terminal but got error .. i will upload after getting home

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to run

```
php artisan schedule:run
```

and At last you can manage this command on scheduling task, you have to add a single entry to your server’s crontab file

```
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

or

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

follow this [tutorial](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/task-scheduling-with-cron-job-in-laravel-58example.html), simple and very useful

Comment: let me try this one sir@MuhammadFarhanAli

Comment: @MuhammadAhmed sure

Comment: i tried but not worked may be i have not  used correctly ... i am sending a screen shot on it

Comment: @MuhammadAhmed sure that will be more helpful